# Класс наследованный от класса при проверке через typeof говорит что он не равен ему

Tags: c#

подскажите пожалуйста почему c# говорит что класс который наследует другой класс не равен при проверке через `typeof`?
А так же не смотря на то что ВСЕ КЛАССЫ В C# наследованы от класса `object`(`System.Object`) говорит мне что typeof == FALSE
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `typeof` возвращает мета-описание класса - уникальное для каждого типа.

Используйте

```
typeof(Testing).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Test)) // false
typeof(Test).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Testing)) // true
```

Comment: `IsAssignableFrom`?

Comment: вот такой же вопрос, потому что vs говорит что такой функции не существует

Comment: @СлаваНосков vs ошибается (.NET 5)

Comment: @aepot это тоже

Comment: `IsAssignableTo` - [Доступна начиная с .NET 5](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignableto?view=net-5.0), используйте `IsAssignableFrom`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, как только выставил NET5, то vs тоже сказала что существует